# Pegar o id selecionado em um content

Tags: php

estou desenvolvendo um fórum em PHP para treinar mesmo e aí tenho a seguinte situação, um content na página de index que tem as categorias criadas, aí quero que conforme seja selecionado uma categoria, sejam dispostos todos os tópicos criados dentro dela, porém estou com um problema para capturar o $id, pois sempre que pego a variável global e jogo no SELECT retorna o mesmo valor, que seria o primeiro da tabela. Espero ter sido claro, valeu migos. Código:

***Parte do index que mostra as categorias:***

**

```
<div id="content">
            <?php
                include_once('server.php');
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM genero ORDER BY titulo_genero ASC";
                $res = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
                $cat = "";

                if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                        $id_view = $row['id'];
                        $titulo = $row['titulo_genero'];    
                        $descricao = $row['desc_genero'];
                        $cat .= "<a href='view.php' class='cat_links'>".$titulo." - <font size='-1'>".$descricao."</a>";
                    }   
                    echo $cat;  
                }else{
                    echo "<p>Nenhum gênero inserido ainda!</p>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

***View dos tópicos por categoria***

```
$sql = "SELECT
            id,
            titulo_genero,
            desc_genero
        FROM
            genero
        WHERE
            id = '$id_view'";


$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

if(!$result)
{
    echo 'Não foi possível acessar a categoria desejada.' . mysqli_error($db);
}
else
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        echo 'O genêro não existe.';
    }
    else
    {
        //display category data
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo '<h2>Topicos em ′' . $row['titulo_genero'] . '′ </h2>';
        }

        //roda a query para os tópicos
        $sql = "SELECT  
                    topic_id,
                    topic_subject,
                    topic_date,
                    topic_cat
                FROM
                    topics
                WHERE
                    topic_cat = '$id_view'";


        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        if(!$result)
        {
            echo 'Não foi possível listar os tópicos, tente de novo.';
        }
        else
        {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
            {
                echo 'Nenhum tópico foi criado nessa categoria ainda.';
            }
            else
            {
                //preparando a tabela
                echo '<table border="1">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Tópico</th>
                        <th>Criado em</th>
                      </tr>'; 

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {               
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="input-group">';
                            echo '<h3><a href="topic.php?id=' . $row['topic_id'] . '">' . $row['topic_subject'] . '</a><h3>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="input-group">';
                            echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['topic_date']));
                        echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No caso, quando chamo o $id_view, queria pegar o id que o usuário selecionou dentro do content, mas não sei como fazer isso. Se eu só chamo o $id_view sempre vou acessar o mesmo, que é o primeiro que foi inserido no banco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

um dato pode ser passado por SESSION[] o cookie.
mas nesse caso vc nao sabe o que salvar na session o coockie e a saluçao seria colocar a categoria pelo url e pegar ela denovo na pagina view

```
$cat .= "<a href='view.php?categoria=".$id_view."' class='cat_links'>".$titulo." - <font size='-1'>".$descricao."</a>";
```

e na pagina view.php voce pega o dato que esta na url no seguinte modo

```
/////////////

if(isset($_GET['categoria']))
{
    $id_view = $_GET['categoria'];
    $sql = "SELECT
            id,
            titulo_genero,
            desc_genero
        FROM
            genero
        WHERE
            id = '$id_view'";
     $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

}
////////////

if(!$result)
{
    echo 'Não foi possível acessar a categoria desejada.' . mysqli_error($db);
}
else
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        echo 'O genêro não existe.';
    }
    else
    {
        //display category data
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo '<h2>Topicos em ′' . $row['titulo_genero'] . '′ </h2>';
        }

        //roda a query para os tópicos
        $sql = "SELECT  
                    topic_id,
                    topic_subject,
                    topic_date,
                    topic_cat
                FROM
                    topics
                WHERE
                    topic_cat = '$id_view'";


        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        if(!$result)
        {
            echo 'Não foi possível listar os tópicos, tente de novo.';
        }
        else
        {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
            {
                echo 'Nenhum tópico foi criado nessa categoria ainda.';
            }
            else
            {
                //preparando a tabela
                echo '<table border="1">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Tópico</th>
                        <th>Criado em</th>
                      </tr>'; 

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {               
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="input-group">';
                            echo '<h3><a href="topic.php?id=' . $row['topic_id'] . '">' . $row['topic_subject'] . '</a><h3>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="input-group">';
                            echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['topic_date']));
                        echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

espero ter ajudado

Comment: Eddy, muito muito obrigado! Que simples né, ainda tenho muito a aprender.... Funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: um prazer te ajudar, todos temos sempre algo pra aprender